# Spring @Constraint annotation cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a custom annotation for my *Spring Boot* application. However i cannot seem to resolve the `@Constraint` annotation required to create the `@Interface`. Below is my code

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface ValidateUser {
}


class UserValidator{

}
```

See attached image showing the `@Constraint` annotation red out
[image]

Comment: Have you added `javax.validation` maven dependencies? Its required for @Contraint. link : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final

Comment: Follow this tutorial it has what you need I guess https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints

Comment: Thank you so much this does the trick , couldn't have found it , it not there in the documentation. Kindly put it as an answer and i will accept it . I might help someone someday.

Comment: yes i might have missed the adding of maven dependency part. Thank you